# How can I disable voice commands (Google Assistant and Amazon Alexa) on iRobot?

Tags: security, privacy, voice-recognition, microphones

I have 2x iRobot (vacuum cleaner and mop) and use their proprietary app, but block internet access for both iRobots on OpenWrt firewall.

Now I want to disable voice commands (Google Assistant and Amazon Alexa) completely, but have not found an option to do so. For example, Apple's HomePod has the option to turn off Siri during setup.

Comment: How is the iRobot connected to Alexa/Google Home? Can you not just not set it up?

Comment: @Helmar I did no specifically enable Alexa/Google assistant. Just connected iRobot to iRobot Home app and WLAN. This is all I did.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the bottom of the Devices page in the Alexa mobile app there is a link to "YOUR SMART HOME SKILLS". I would look to see if there is an iRobot skill and unlink it.

Likewise user settings in the Google Home app at the bottom of the list there is "Works with Google" that should list all the Actions you have linked. Again look for the iRobot skill and unlink it.

This is all hypothetical as I don't have an iRobot device and I would be courious how they managed to link to both Google Assistant and Alexa without an explicit act as it should require a full oAuth handshake for both Google and Amazon to set this up...